# MongoDB as docker container - how to import documents from external file

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoimport

I have a mongoDB as a docker container. I'd like to run:

```
mongoimport C:\Users\Me\Desktop\tv-shows.json -d movieData -c movies --jsonArray --drop
```

but the path is wrong. Should I first put my json file to the mongo container?

How can I import my documents in my json file?

SO far I get the error:

> E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token:
>   identifier : @(shell):1:12

Comment: With Docker containers there is the concept of host vs. container.  The context of where you is important.  You did not say if you were attempting to import from the host or from the container.  Where are you trying to run this command from?

Answer (score 0):

you can use mongo compass to import-export drop or do similar basic functions easily than this if you wish to drop an existing collection and import new ones.

[image]